# Is JPA's @TableGenerator "gapless"

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I need to implement "gapless" id. I have been looking around for some solution with table stored last value. I have been wondering if @TableGenerator can be of some help. I am unable to find out how the value is gathered from database(i.e. is there some pesimistic locking?). Otherwise I will need to manage the locking manually.

Comment: There are several different table generators some of which operate on sequences which probably is what you want. Besides that you might want to elaborate on what "gapless" means in your context, e.g. what happens with deleted entities etc.?

Comment: Sequences are not gapless. Once you got the sequence, it is never put back, thus you are ending with unused "gaps".

Comment: That depends on the allocation size you're using (which affects performance though). Besides that you could write your own allocator which takes care of any gaps.

Comment: Why do you care whether some meaningless ID is gapless? IDs provide  unique surrogate keys and serve no other purpose.

Comment: Imagine law enforced invoice numbering. So actually it is not primary key as it needs to be reset every year. Just wandering how the TableGenerator works under the hood.